# PHP file upload frustration

Tags: php, html

Good morning all

I have been playing around with setting up a file upload function on my HTML form and just cant get the file to actually upload onto my server. The directory is named /uploads and is in my root where the index file etc is housed. The form has the right enctype etc and the PHP does not return any errors, i just cant get the file to upload. Please help me ....

The HTML for my input field is :

```
<td valign="top">File Upload</label></td>
 <td valign="top"><input name="file" type="file" /></td>
```

PHP is :

```
   $uploads_dir = "http://www.tenancydepositservice.co.uk/uploads";

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");}

     $email_message .= "$uploads_dir/$name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong temp name it should be

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
```

you had

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

also make sure the form has

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

And the file save path is as

```
$uploads_dir = "path to upload"
```

something as

```
$uploads_dir = "/var/www/project/upload_dir"
```

having `upload_dir` with write permission.

Comment: Thanks , is my path totally wrong then ? basically, my PHP handler is in a folder called ' mailers ' and this is situated in the root folder, the folder I want to place my upload into is called ' uploads ' and is in the root also ?

Comment: so it could be /mailers/uploads/ u can also have full path depending on the server EX. /var/www/mailers/uploads in linux.

Comment: Is there a way I can find out the true path of this folder as all the combinations I seem to use are wrong. I am getting the error that the path is not recognised. I am using Firezilla as my FTP.

Comment: well u can use ftp to locate the folder. Some hosting provider will only give u access to your root folder so u can use directly as /your_project/uploadfolder/

Comment: Abhik, you are a star, I now have the file uploading and the email being sent through. Just one last question please if you can answer, once the email has come through then I click on the link to see the file and I get this .... ' Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR  ' Can you shed any light on this for me please ?

Comment: I see you probably does not have SSL cert installed on the server. In that case I would suggest to send the email with the URL as http:// not https:// until the SSL CERT is installed in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

the php part / file:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    $uploads_dir = './uploads';
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $allowed_type = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'); //this is for images but can be changed to any type of file
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $path = $uploads_dir.$file_name;

    if(isset($file_name) && !empty($file_name)) {
        if(in_array($file_type, $allowed_type)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path);
            //if you need to store the file in a db use $path in your query
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Copied from w3schools.com

```
   <?php


    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
       {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      }
      $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");    //add your extension here
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")            //add extension here as well
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))     //create a folder 
          {                                                    //named upload where your 
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";  //all php pages are stored
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
        }
        else
        {
         echo "Invalid file";
        }

   ?>
```

look at // in code

Comment: This is a very wide of the mark answer to a specific problem that I am having.